# DC motor speed control by aurdino using processing

Tags: processing, arduino-uno

I have attached video link. In this the DC motor speed is controlled by using **Aurdino Uno and the processing software** by moving the cursor of the laptop. But I want to control it with the laptop **aero keys**. So please send me the modified program if possible.

https://youtu.be/SQDawyCRFu0

You can find program on this:http://www.instructables.com/id/Speed-control-of-dc-motor-from-laptop-using-arduin/

Comment: @Juhana Why did you remove the [tag:processing] tag?

Answer (score 1):

Please consult [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) and you'll find some handy input functions, including the [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) function. You can use that to get input from the arrow keys.

```
void keyPressed(){
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      //up
    } 
    else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      //down
    } 
    else if(keyCode == LEFT){
      //left
    }
    else if(keyCode == RIGHT){
     //right 
    }
}
```

More info can be found in [this tutorial on user input in Processing](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). (Note: I wrote this tutorial.)

By the way, it's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to the reference and Google. Stack Overflow is designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So you really need to do some research (Googling something like "Processing arrow keys" would have gotten you pretty far) and then post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not an external link) if you get stuck. Good luck.